# How to use docker's Rosetta 2 x86_64 emulation when building a docker image on arm64 system architecture?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-build, rosetta-2

A dockerfile that builds successfully on a laptop with intel chip doesn't successfully build on a laptop that has an M2/arm/apple silicon chip.

How can I emulate the x86_64/amd64 environment on the arm based mac using Rosetta 2?

#### What I know so far

- [This](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384#issuecomment-1377337935) comment on a GitHub issue mentions Docker Desktop will support emulation of x86_64 architecture in early 2023, so I updated Docker Desktop to the most recent version (4.17.0).
- [This](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384#issuecomment-1380882630) comment shows a checkbox titled *Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon*, which I checked (and also ensured [*Virtualization framework in turned on in the General settings tab*](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/mac/) is on.
- I restarted both docker and terminal.

Is anything else necessary in order to make the `docker build` command build for x86_64 architecture using Rosetta 2 emulation, and how can I confirm that it's working as intended?

Comment: Using Docker Desktop v4.20 and that Rosetta checkbox is no longer listed in settings...

Answer (score 4):

You can add --platform linux/amd64 to run (or build) an Intel image using emulation, in the latest docker version.

Answer (score 3):

No that should suffice. Once your X64 docker container is started, you can enter the command line into the docker container and then type `ps -ef`. You should then see a list of processes running inside the docker. Each X64 process should be preceded by `/rosetta/rosetta`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can output the hardware platform with the uname command.

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 --rm nginx uname -m
x86_64
```

```
docker run --rm nginx uname -m                   
aarch64
```

This is the host:

```
uname -mrspv
Darwin 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 22:22:19 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64 arm
```

Docker Desktop 4.21.1 with `Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon` on in experimental settings.